# Consultas combinadas sqlite python

Tags: python, sqlite3

buenas. Estoy intentando modificar esta función:

```
cursor = base.cursor()
data = (estado, )
sql = "SELECT id, título, autor, editorial, isbn, pvp FROM ejemplares WHERE estado = ? ORDER BY id"
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

para que el usuario pueda generar su propia combinación de búsquedas más allá de las predefinidas que yo cree.
He llegado hasta esta instancia:

```
cursor = base.cursor()

datos=["","","","",""]
if prod:
    datos[0] =prod 
if estado:
    datos[1] = estado
if tipo:
    datos[2] = tipo
if gen:
    datos[3] = gen
if sub_gen:
    datos[4] = sub_gen
print("print de datos:", datos)
print("tipo de datos",type(datos))
data = tuple(datos)
print("print de data:",data)
print("tipo de data",type(datos))
sql = "SELECT id, título, autor, editorial, isbn, pvp FROM ejemplares WHERE producto = ? AND estado = ? AND categoría = ? AND género = ? AND subgénero = ? ORDER BY id"
cursor.execute(sql, data)
dato = cursor.fetchall()
print(dato)
```

Pero la consulta no devuelve nada (el print(dato) me muestra la consulta vacía).
¿Cómo podría asignarle los valores a la sentencia sql?

Comment: Tendrás que crear una consulta dinamica cuyo where dependa de lo ingresado por el usuario. También, asegurate de dificultar la inyección sql

Comment: Gracias. ¿Conoces algún tutorial sobre consultas dinámicas que tenga en cuenta Python y Sqlite3?

Comment: Una consulta dinamica no es más que una consulta hecha usando formateo de cadenas. Algo como `f"select * from tabla where {columna}='hola'"` donde columna es el nombre de una columna. Obviamente, por la forma de generar esta consulta, el código resulta vulnerable a la [inyección sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), por eso es importante que manejes eso con cuidado. Si te animás a adaptarte a algo nuevo y diferente, [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) es de mucha ayuda, tiene compatibilidad con muchos modulos de bases de datos, incluyendo sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando `OR` en lugar de `AND`, para `AND` tendrían que cumplirse todas las condiciones, para `OR` serian opcionales:

```
sql = "SELECT id, título, autor, editorial, isbn, pvp FROM ejemplares 
WHERE producto = ? OR estado = ? OR categoría = ? OR género = ? OR subgénero = ?
ORDER BY id"
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que esta idea aplica unicamente si se quiere filtrar usando una sola columna. Si el usuario quisiese, por ejemplo obtener el producto "computadora" cuyo estado es "comprado" mostraría todos las las computadoras y todos los productos comprados.